# Notice: Trying to get property ..... of non-object

Tags: php, properties

This code was working for several months perfectly fine...

```
 if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) {                   
        $recipe_name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE ID =".$id);                                 
                    echo $recipe_name->recipe_name; }
```

It used to return the name of my recipe, but now I only get

> Notice: Trying to get property 'recipe_name' of non-object in .... on
> line 48

when I try

```
var_dump ($recipe_name);
```

I get NULL ,
All of the information is sitting in the database and the recipe_name is certainly not null. What has happened?

I have tried to change `echo $recipe_name->recipe_name;` to `echo $recipe_name['recipe_name'];` but i only get another error

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in.....

Comment: Thank you to Bergi for editing my 1st question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `$id` you're using in this block is not being defined as `$_GET['id']` and appears to be coming from somewhere else in the code since you're not getting an unset variable error.

Since your query is returning `null` it's likely that whatever `$id` was at some point is being changed or cleared.

Try this, which validates that `$_GET['id']` exists, is not empty, and then uses it as the query parameter. I've also cleaned up your string and changed the echo to return a default value if the recipe can't be found for some reason.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) {
    $recipe_name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE ID = {$_GET['id']}");                                 
    echo isset($recipe_name) ? $recipe_name->recipe_name : 'Recipe Name';
}
```

I'd also suggest changing `$recipe_name` to `$recipe` for clarity, but I didn't change this because I'm unsure if you're using it anywhere else on the page.

You might want to [prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) your query with a bind parameter as well, because dropping a `$_GET` variable into a query this way exposes you to the possibility of a [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) attack. Based on your connection being named `$wpdb` I assume you're using WordPress, and something like this (where `%d` validates a digit) should take care of the problem.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE ID = %d", $_GET['id']);
    $recipe_name = $wpdb->get_row($prepared_query);
    echo isset($recipe_name) ? $recipe_name->recipe_name : 'Recipe Name';
}
```

*Side note, the reason replacing `->recipe_name` with `['recipe_name']` changed the error is because `$wpdb->get_row` returns a class object (accessed with `->`) while brackets `[]` indicate an associative array. They're two different types of data.*

Comment: Thank you! This piece ... WHERE ID = {$_GET['id']}"); ... is what solved the issue. Yes, I was using $id = $_GET['id']; in the top of the code and it had been working all along until recently when it stopped working. Adding your fix to every line where I am populating information from the database has fixed the error. I am still trying to understand what made the issue start happening in the first place.